# My implementation of the binary search tree is not working because I keep getting error that my node and typedef item is not defined

Tags: c++

The important part is the header file for some reason when I include it to the implementation file it does not include the struct node I made or the typedef did I do anything wrong? I have never had this problem before and have done it numerous times. Do you guys have any suggestions? this is the error I am getting Node was not declared in this scope and item does not name a type.

```
//Header File
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#ifndef BST
using namespace std;
class BST
{
 public:
  typedef int item;

  //constructors
  BST() {root =NULL;}

  // Destructor
  ~BST();

  //Modification member functions
  void reinitialize();
  void insert( const item& entry);
  void remove( const item& target);

  // constant member functions

  bool empty() const{return root == NULL;}
  int length();
  bool present(const item& target);



  // definitions
 private:

  struct Node//my structure
  {
    item data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
  };
  Node *root;

  //recursive functions
  void print(Node *p);
  void destroy(Node *r);
  void help_insert(Node *&t, const item& entry);
  void help_remove(Node *&t, const item& entry);
  void remove_node(Node *&t);


};
#define BST

#endif
```

**Source file**

```
//Implementation of the Binary search tree
//Kyle Ripplinger
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "BST.h"
using namespace std;
/*BST::~BST()
{
  destroy(root);
}
void BST::destroy(Node *r)//doesn't work here
{
  if(r!= NULL)
    {
      destroy(r->left);
      destroy(r->right);
      delete r;
    }
}
int BST::length()
{
  return find_length(root);// doesnt work
}
int BST::find_length(Node *r)
{
  if (r== NULL)
    return 0;
  else 
    return find_length(r->left)+1+find_length(r->right);
    }*/
void BST:: insert(const item& entry)
{
  help_insert(root, entry);
}
void BST:: help_insert(Node *&t,const item& entry)
{
  if(t == NULL)
    {
      t = new Node;
      t -> data = entry;
      t -> left = NULL;
      t -> right = NULL;
    }
  else if(entry <t->data)
    help_insert(t->left,entry);
  else
    help_insert(t->right,entry);
}
void BST:: remove(const item& target)
{
  assert(present(target));
  help_remove(root,target);
}
void BST:: help_remove(Node *&t, const item& target)
{
  if {t->data = target)
    remove_node(t);
    else if(target < t->data)
      help_remove(t->left, target);
    else
      help_remove(t->right, target);
}
void BST:: remove_node(Node *&t)
{
  Node *ptr;
  Node *back;
  if(t->left == NULL && t->right == NULL)//leaf
    {
      delete t;
      t = NULL;
    }
  else if(t->left == NULL)//has right child only
    {
      ptr = t;
      t = t->right;
      delete ptr;
    }
  else if(t ->right == NULL)//has left child only
    {
      ptr = t;
      t = t->left;
      delete ptr;
    }
  else//has both children on tree find the leftmost node in the right subtree
    {
      back = t;
      ptr = t->right;
      while(ptr->left != NULL)
    {
      back = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->left;
    }
      t->data = ptr->data;
      if(back == t)
    remove_node(back->right);
      else
    remove_node(back->left);
    }
}
bool BST::present(Item target)
{
  Node *p;
  p = root;
  while(true)
    {
      if(p == NULL)
    return false;
      else if (target < p-> data)
    p = p->left;
      else if(target == p->data)
    return true;
      else
    p= p-> right;
    }
}
/*void BST::print(Node *p)
{
  if(p!=NULL)
    {
      print(p->left);
      cout << p-> data << endl;
      print(p->right);
    }
    }*/
```

Comment: At the end of the header, you define `BST` as a macro expanding to nothing. Then `int BST::find_length(Node *r)` expands to `int ::find_length(Node *r)` - this defines a regular non-member function. Since it's not in scope of class `BST`, the name `Node` is not visible. Why on the good green Earth did you decide to define that macro?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct. Because of your include guard, your definition of

```
void BST::insert(const item& entry)
```

became

```
void ::insert(const item& entry)
```

and there is no type called `item` in the global context.

---

Debugging tip: to try to point the compiler in the right direction, I changed that first line of your declaration to

```
void BST::insert(const BST::item& entry)
```

When the compiler reported "`error: 'item' in namespace '::' does not name a type`", it was rather clear that the `BST` was disappearing somehow.

Comment: The take away here is to be very cautious when reusing an identifier.

Comment: True. Naming conventions can really help. I like the convention where include guards -- and *only* include guards -- end in `_H` or `_HPP`.